# Youtube Live Chat in Iframe (without API)

Tags: iframe, youtube, chat, live

How is it possible to put the Youtube Live Chat into an Iframe?
I have this URL, but for me it does not work:

```
<iframe allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0" height="270" src="https://www.youtube.com/live_chat?v={VIDEO_ID}&embed_domain={MY_DOMAIN}" width="480"></iframe>
```

If I open the URL normally in the Browser, I get the chat, but in the Iframe i get nothing.

Please help. Thx :)

Comment: Check the browser console - most likely there's a message there, saying YT forbid this via the `X-Frame-Options` header. Little you can do about that, unless you want to proxy everything. If they want you to use the API, then use the API.

Comment: But look here: https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/2524549?hl=en

Comment: a) at what specifically, and b) you look here: [ask] and here: [mcve], please.

Comment: Possible duplicate of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/52468303 (with more answers available there).

Answer (score 1):

It says it's possible, but only on Desktop browsers:

> Note: embedding live chat isn't available on mobile web.
>
> During a live stream, you can embed live chat on your own site by
>   using an iframe.
>
> Get the video ID for the live stream. You can get the video ID from the watch page URL (youtube.com/watch?v=12345). In this case, the video ID is ‘12345’. If you chose "Stream now," right-click on the player and select Copy video URL to get the video URL.
>
> Get the domain URL for the site you want to embed chat on. If you're embedding chat on www.example.com/youtube_chat, your embedding domain is "www.example.com."
>
> Combine the embedded URL in the following way: https://www.youtube.com/live_chat?v=12345&embed_domain=www.example.com
>
> This is the URL for your iframe. Note the embed_domain must match the URL of the page you’re embedding the chat on. If they are different, the embedded chat will not load.

https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/2524549?hl=en

I made an example with:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/5qap5aO4i9A" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
<iframe width="185" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/live_chat?v=5qap5aO4i9A&embed_domain=fiddle.jshell.net" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Which looks like this:

[image]

View the working demo here:
https://jsfiddle.net/kmturley/9Lmbdgn2/8/

Answer (score 0):

You may need to have embedding enabled first, you can check the status of your account at this link after you're logged in the youtube account: https://www.youtube.com/features

Also the domain part (MY_DOMAIN) needs to be without the 'https://' or 'http://' and port numbers like ':3000'